# Frequency of pattern occurring in a string using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm

**Question**:

Given a string S with n characters and a pattern P with k characters,
a natural question that arises is how frequently does `P` appear in S. For example, if `S = CGATATATCCATAG` and `P = ATA`, then P appears three times in `S`; that is, `FREQ(S,P) = 3`. On the other hand, when `P′ = AAT`, `FREQ(S,P′) = 0` because there are no 3-letter sequences in `S` equal to `AAT`.

a. Given S and P, design a brute force algorithm (i.e., the most basic algorithm possible) that outputs `FREQ(S,P)`. What is the running time of your algorithm? Your answer should be in terms of n and k.

b. This time around, design a divide and conquer algorithm that outputs `FREQ(S,P)`. What is the running time of your algorithm? Your answer should be in terms of `n` and `k`.

**Solution**:

a) we use a moving window approach to check all the possibilities.

```
def FREQ(S,k):
  count = 0
  for i in [0...length(S) - k]:
    if S.substring(i, length(k)) == k:
      count = count + 1
  
  return count
```

This loops run `length(S) - length(k) + 1` times so this algorithm runs `O(|S| - |k| + 1)` times.

b) I am not sure how to use divide and conquer instead, and not sure whether anything would beat a linear time complexity.

Comment: `k` is a confusing variable name here (the problem says `P`) and that's probably why you wrote `k` instead of `length(k)` in line 3. But anyway, `S.substring(i, length(k)) == k` is not a linear-time operation; it takes O(|P|) to do the comparison. (Many JS implementations can slice strings in O(1), by just returning the start and stop indexes; that works because the underlying string is immutable. But that doesn't help with the cost of the comparison.) That makes the algorithm O(|S|*|P|) andit can be improved to O(|S|). But I also don't don't know how to use divde & conquer to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your pattern matching approach to make it use divide and conquer.

1. Divide `S` into two halves `L` and `R`. Let `l = FREQ(L,P)` and `r = FREQ(R,P)`.
2. You've covered all occurrences that occur in either half of the string. The only ones left are the ones that start in the left half, but end in the right half. Let the count of such occurrences be `x`.
3. If `k >= n`, `x = 0`. Else, use a sliding window technique to find the occurrences between indices `[n/2 - k + 1, n/2 + k - 1]`.
4. `FREQ(S,P) = l + r + x`.

The recurrence relation can be given as `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2k`, so you can easily calculate the time complexity for the D&C approach.